# Кастомный макет Android

Tags: android, mobile-development, imageview

Суть в том что есть макет который состоит из разных изображений. Нужно его отобразить на экране. Использование DP не помогает, так как оно начинает конкретно "съезжать". Написал свой класс который ресайзит картинкипо пикселям, то есть берет коэфициент для данного экрана относительно стандартных изображений и  отсупов и перерисовывает их. Но такой подход кушает много оперативной памяти. Кто что подскажет?

Comment: Учиться верстать "резиновый" (адаптивный) дизайн. Про то, как это делать, можно и книгу написать :)  Попиксельные картинки это тупик - под андроид огромное количество устройств с самыми разными размерами экрана, разрешениями и плотностями - под все не нарежешь.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что вы слишком легко и просто попрощались с dp, и этой единице измерения необходимо немножко больше внимания, чтоб всё заработало так, как хотите вы.

Рекомендую учитывать оснонвые принципы, которые обуславливаются модификаторами в ресурсах и это действительно очень удобно:

1.Размер экрана.

2.Плотность Экрана.

3.Разрешения экрана.

4.Ориентация экрана.

Вы можете открыть DashboardAndroid и посмотреть какие параметры сейчас более популярны и работать изначально из под них, заранее уже захватив большую часть рынка.

Более того не используя данный подход, вы лишаетесь многим принципам дизайна. 
Потому что на разных экранах, на разных устройства - интерфейс должен смотреться идентично, НО! для этого иногда приходится практически все элементы переместить или даже добавить новые. (phone/tablet/tv/wear) Что также легко учитывать модификаторами, выбор за вами.